# Создать массив обьектов вроде obj0 obj1 obj2 obj3

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно что-то вроде

```
for (var i=0; i<HowManyObjects; i++) {
создать объект с названием "obj"+i;
массив объектов[i]=только что созданный объект
}
```

Не представляю как сделать массив с "перечислеными" объектами.

Comment: Хоть язык скажи... JavaScript?

Comment: Да, только что изменил метку

Comment: Что значит "_создать объект с названием ..._"? Имеется в виду строка или что-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это JavaScript, то вот так можно создать массив arr и заполнить его требуемыми строками. Метод push добавляет элемент в конец массива.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<HowManyObjects; i++) {
    arr.push("obj"+i);
}
```

Comment: или `arr.push({ name: "obj"+i });`

Comment: @Igor, да, если требуется в массив класть объекты, но общий смысл один и тот же)

Comment: Спасибо, прояснили

Comment: @qwerty17, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте его галочкой.